# React Attach State Directly to Instance

Tags: reactjs

Why is it good practice to assign state variables to React's state? I'm a react beginner. I'm trying to understand the purpose of a separate `state` object. Naively, it seems just as good (and a little shorter), to write in a component:

```
this.foo = 3;
```

instead of:

```
this.state.foo = 3;
```

I understand that `setState` triggers a rerender, but it seems you could just easily set the state you want and then trigger a rerender directly. I've been using `this.setState({})`.

In all other cases, React appears to adhere to principles of simplicity. React tends to favor native JavaScript functionality over additional React-defined functionality except where additional functionality is absolutely required. Why did the creators of React go out of their way to give React `state`?

#### In-Depth Example

As a longer example, I can define a component `Counter` that increases its count every second. The first way uses react's `state` property. The second attaches its state directly to the instance.

Using `state`:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {count: 0};

        setInterval((() => {
            this.setState(previousState => ({ 
                count: previousState.count + 1 }));
        }), 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>;
    }
}
```

Attaching properties directly to the instance:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.count = 0;

        setInterval((() => {
            this.count += 1;
            this.setState({})
        }), 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>{this.count}</h1>;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my mind, it's just about being explicit. The state is represented by this specific thing, so it knows to re-render when that changes. Otherwise, as you said, you would need to manually trigger a render when you know something in your class level vars have changed. Or alternatively use some method to make those specific pieces observable.